# android studio Error:Execution failed for task '*****_library:processReleaseManifest'. > Format specifier '20g'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I have a error since several days:

```
Error:Execution failed for task   ':nameproject_library:processReleaseManifest'.
```

> Format specifier '20g'

I have a projet app and a library, i search a lot in stackoverflow and google but all solutions doesn't work for me

build.gradle library:

build.gradle mylibrary :

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
  repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  jcenter()
   maven { url 'http://xxxxxx:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/' }
  //maven  { url "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2" }

  }
  buildscript {
  repositories {
     mavenCentral()
    }
   dependencies {
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
    } 
    }
   apply plugin: 'android-apt'
   def AAVersion = '3.1'
   apt {
   arguments {
    androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
   }
  }
  android {
  compileSdkVersion 23
  buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
   }
   buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
    }
  } 
    packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
   }
   }

  dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
  apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
  compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
  compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
   compile(
         [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core',  version:   '1.9.9'],
         [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version: '2.1.1'],
        [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.1.2']

 )
  compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.1.0'
  compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.48'
  compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
  compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13'
  compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
  compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.0'
  compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-   
  template:1.0.1.RELEASE'
  compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
  compile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-  
   crypto:3.1.4.RELEASE') {
     exclude group: 'org.springframework', module: 'spring-core'
   }

  //Dependency for Twitter
  compile files('libs/signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1.jar')
  compile files('libs/signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar')
  compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-4.0.2.jar')
  compile files('libs/twitter4j-media-support-3.0.3.jar')

  //Dependency for Facebook
  //compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.3.0'

  // Dependency for Google Sign-In
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'

  // Dependency for Location
  //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'

   }

   //google plus
  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

build.gradle app :

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 repositories {
 mavenCentral()
 jcenter()
 maven { url 'http://********:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/' }
 }
 buildscript {
 repositories {
    mavenCentral()
 }
 dependencies {
     classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
 }
 }
 apply plugin: 'android-apt'
 def AAVersion = '3.1'

apt {
arguments {
    androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
 }
}
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "fr.assuristance.presentation"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),   
 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
  }
}
dependencies {
compile project(':filassistance_library')
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"

 }
```

With --stacktrace i get

org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:mockableAndroidJar'.

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally resolve the problem

The error Format specifier '20g', coming from the path of project, a folder contains " %"

After that i still have an error: Error:Execution failed for task '::processReleaseResources'. > at index 4

And also in Android SDK i noticed there were a broken sdk tools (i suspect that become broken after i update android studio), so i just delete them and the build now work